# Single database between more than one application

Tags: java, web-services

I have one desktop application (built in Swing) and two web applications (built on Struts and hibernate framework) that are sharing same database. Basically all data manipulations and insertions are done by desktop application remotely connecting to database while the web applications are mainly used for presenting data to the user and also have some download and mailing operations.
For now, each of the three applications create their own database connection from the single database and perform their own set of operations and then close them when not needed.

Although, I haven't encountered any performance issue or may be I haven't realized it even if there are any. But still, this kind of architecture appear to me a bit clumsy and complex. Therefore, I have decided to re-engineer these applications. 
For database operations, I am considering for creating a set of web services that will perform the DDL or DML operations. My applications will hit these web services according to the operation they want to perform and get the result.

So in first place, I want to know if exposing the DB operations through web services are recommended considering the fact that it also have DML operations. Any other ideas that can improve current solution are also welcomed.

Comment: Why do you think the current solution needs to be improved? Any concrete problems you are facing?

Comment: No as such. But I believe this will be more efficient way to talk to database. Creating web services for database will allow me to have a single unit which will talk to db and all application will tie to it. But I am not sure if this is a feasible approach in real time.